# verb-ている in potential form やってられないよ

Tags: grammar, set-phrases, phrases

A girl is moaning about how she is treated for not doing her homework then pauses and says:

> やってられないよ

I assume this is a contraction of やっていられないよ which would literally be "I can't be doing it". I've never seen the verb-ている form converted to potential before. Is it a common thing and how does it differ from, for example, やれない in this case?

Maybe I'm barking up the wrong tree entirely. Either way, I don't understand what meaning this sentence is supposed to convey.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you stated,

> 「やってられないよ」＝「やって**い**られないよ」

More informally, you will often hear:

> 「やって**らん**ないよ」 or even 「やって**らんねえ**よ」 around Kanto (therefore, in fiction as well).

It would probably be better to treat a common phrase like 「やって（い）られない」 as a set phrase rather than breaking it down to understand it.

***It simply means "I can't stand it anymore!"  You are saying what is happening is ridiculous.***

> "I've never seen the verb-ている form converted to potential before."

Really?  It is used quite often.  We say things like:

「つまんねえ[映画]{えいが}！[観]{み}てられないよ～！」"What a boring movie!  I can't watch it anymore!"

「[変]{へん}な[曲]{きょく}！[聴]{き}いてられねえ！」"Weird tune!  Can't be listening to it!"

「こんなマズいピザ[食]{た}べてらんねえぜ！」"I can't be eating an awful pizza like this!"

Whether you use the present progressive in your translation or not would be up to you.